# Kidvar HaMelech VeDoso

Tags: megillat-esther, malchut-royalty

It is well known that whenever it says HaMelech without the name Achashveirosh in Megillas Esther, it is referring to Hashem. What then is the meaning of Perek 4 Posuk 3, where, in reference to the letters Achashveirosh sent out, they were according to HaMelech and His law?

Comment: Perl the Tag about Gaon miVilna was removed. The reason is that in the body of the question you did not mention that the principle you set out about the word Hamelech is known as a part of the commentary of the Gaon al pi haremez in name of the midrash. May be a good Idea to add a link. [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39741&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=) is a link if this can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps its referring to this (that Hashem had sealed the decree):

"באותה שעה רץ אליהו זכור לטוב בבהלה אצל אבות העולם, ואצל משה בן עמרם, ואמר להם: עד מתי אבות העולם רדומים בשינה, ואי אתם משגיחים על הצרה שבניכם שרויין בה?... אמרו לו: מפני מה? אמר להם: מפני שנהנו ישראל מסעודתו של אחשוורוש, ובעבור זאת נגזרה עליהם גזירה לכלותם מן העולם ולאבד את זכרם...

אמר לו משה: כלום יש אדם כשר באותו הדור?

אמר לו: יש, ושמו מרדכי.

אמר לו: לך והודיעו, כדי שיעמוד הוא משם בתפילה, ואני מכאן, ונבקש רחמים עליהם לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא.

אמר לו: רועה נאמן, כבר נכתבה אגרת כלייה על ישראל.

אמר לו משה: אם בטיט היא חתומה תפלתנו נשמעת, ואם בדם נחתמה מה שהיה הוא.

אמר לו: בטיט היא חתומה.

אמר לו משה רבנו: לך והודיע למרדכי. מיד הלך והודיע למרדכי".

(אסתר רבה, פרשה ז)

Comment: Please provide a summary of the quote. This website is intended to accomedate those who only speak English.